# fetch data from sql database via php server in react app

Tags: php, reactjs

I am new to coding and a self-learner, I am making a real-time chat application for that i am using React at its frontend rendering and php at its backend with Mysql as database. I am able to insert data in my database using axios but not able to fetch data. Can anyone pls help me out to solve this issue. my react script to get data from php server:

```
   const url = "http://localhost:80/react-backenda/";
const axios = require('axios');
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("SendBy", username);
formData.append("Sendto", "got");
formData.append("Msg", input);

axios.post(url, formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
.then(res=> console.log(res.data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));


}
```

my php script:

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "msg-clone";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if(!$conn){
    die("could not connect to server!");
}

$recText = $_POST['Msg'];
$sendby = $_POST['SendBy'];
$sendto = $_POST['Sendto'];
     echo $recText;
     $sql = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`, `text`, `sendby`, `sendto`, `time`) VALUES (NULL, '$recText', '$sendby', '$sendto', current_timestamp());";
     $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     if ($res){
         echo "done";
     }else {
         echo "err";
 }
?>
```

please tell me how can i get data from my php server to react, ie server side rendering using php of react app. Just simply tell me ways to fetch data from php server to react app.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: You're asking about fetching data but only show how you save data. Please show us your attempt to fetch data and explain where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data with axios get method:

```js
axios.get(url)
.then(res=> console.log(res.data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: i want to fetch data from sql database via php server can you please ellaborate.

Comment: you can do `  $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages"`

Answer (score -1):

Php script to fetch all messages from MySQL.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "msg-clone";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if(!$conn){
    die("could not connect to server!");
}
$sql = mysqli_query($conn ,"Select * from messages");
$result = mysqli_result($sql);
return $result;
?>
```

react script to get the result.

```
axios.get(url)
.then(res=> console.log(res.data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Have a look I hope it's helpful to achieve your goal.
Thanks